# Laying out Labels properly in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *


master = Tk() 
center(master, 300, 200)
#Label(text = 'Clients').grid(row = 0, column = 1) 
lb = Listbox(master, selectmode = BROWSE) 
sb = Scrollbar(master) 
sb.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky =NS, rowspan = 1) 
lb.grid(row = 0, column = 1) 

sb['command'] = lb.yview 
lb['yscrollcommand'] = sb.set

Label(master, text = "AAAAA").grid(row = 0, column = 2) 
Label(master, text = "BBBBB").grid(row = 1, column = 3)


mainloop()
```

Which creates this window:

[image: Screenshot]

I know I can use `sticky = N` to make `AAAAA` cling to the top of the cell and be at the top of the window.

But my question is: How do I make it so that I can put multiple labels next to my listbox widget in a sort of grid of their own? Can I use `.grid` for this? Or do I have to use `.place`?

Or am I going about this entirely wrong?

Comment: Just make the listbox span the rows that correspond to your grid of labels.

Comment: You could use a Frame as parent for your Labels, and then you grid the frame at the right of the Listbox. This is just a solution. It depends on what you really want to obtain. If you show us a picture of what you want to obtain, that might be more helpful.

Comment: @Rinzler Thank you, That's what I've done. Exactly what I needed. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Just did. There are a lot of Tkinter questions on stackoverflow already.